# Python print single byte as char

Tags: python, arrays, byte

I have a long array of bytes and I need to carefully inspect the values at each position. So I want to print it in two columns with byte number and byte value. How can this be done?

Example:

```
bytes = b'hola\x00chau'

print(bytes)
for i,byte in enumerate(bytes):
    print(i,byte)
```

Desired output:

```
b'hola\x00chau'
0 h
1 o
2 l
3 a
4 \x00
5 c
6 h
7 a
8 u
```

The code actually prints the bytes as integers.

Comment: @MichaelButscher it doesn't, the bytes are converted to integers at some point so they are already integers in the `byte` variable of the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer after some experimentation:

```
bytes = b'hola\x00chau'

print(bytes)
for i,byte in enumerate(bytes):
    print(i,byte.to_bytes(1,'big'))
```

produces

```
b'hola\x00chau'
0 b'h'
1 b'o'
2 b'l'
3 b'a'
4 b'\x00'
5 b'c'
6 b'h'
7 b'a'
8 b'u'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to convert back and forth,

```py
data = b'hola\x00chau'

for i in range(len(data)):
    print(i, data[i:i+1].decode("ascii"))
```

produces

```
0 h
1 o
2 l
3 a
4 
5 c
6 h
7 a
8 u
```

and

```py
for i in range(len(data)):
    print(i, data[i:i+1])
```

produces

```
0 b'h'
1 b'o'
2 b'l'
3 b'a'
4 b'\x00'
5 b'c'
6 b'h'
7 b'a'
8 b'u'
```